# Simplifying an expression involving log using euler's constant $\gamma$

Tags: summation, analytic-number-theory

I was wondering if someone could give me a hint or solution on how to obtain the following estimate:
$$
x \log^2 x - 2 x \log x + 2 x + O(\log^2 x)
=
x \log x (\sum_{k \leq x} 1/k)
- \sum_{k \leq x} (\gamma + (\gamma + 2) \log k)
+ O(\log^2 x).
$$
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the well known asymptotic for the harmonic numbers we have $$\sum_{k\leq x}\frac{1}{k}=H_{\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor }=\log\left(x\right)+\gamma+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
 $$ hence $$x\log\left(x\right)\sum_{k\leq x}\frac{1}{k}=x\log^{2}\left(x\right)+\gamma x\log\left(x\right)+O\left(\log\left(x\right)\right)\tag{1}
 $$ about the other sum we have $$\sum_{k\leq x}\left(\gamma+\left(\gamma+2\right)\log\left(k\right)\right)=\gamma x+\left(\gamma+2\right)\sum_{k\leq x}\log\left(k\right)+O\left(1\right)\tag{2}
 $$ so we have to estimate $\sum_{k\leq x}\log\left(k\right)
 $. By partial summation we have $$\sum_{k\leq x}\log\left(k\right)=\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \log\left(x\right)-\int_{1}^{x}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }{t}dt=x\log\left(x\right)-x+O\left(\log\left(x\right)\right)\tag{3}
 $$ so using $(1),\,(2),\,(3)
 $ our claim follows.

Comment: Thank you! By the way how can I show that $\int_1^x \lfloor t \rfloor /t dt = x + O(\log x)?$ Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyT. Using $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor =t+O\left(1\right)$ we have $$\int_{1}^{x}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }{t}dt=\int_{1}^{x}dt+O\left(\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt\right).$$

Comment: Ooops. That was silly of me. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyT. Note that from the proof we have only $O(\log(x))$, so is not necessary $O(\log^{2}(x))$.